# Twitter Authentication/Login for c# Failed

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, twitter-oauth

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
I have given the consumerkey and consumersecret in Start.Auth.cs.

Comment: is answer successful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) documentation

Setting the callback overrides the default behaviour and you can yourself create a custom validation routine.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

Obviously you have to attach the callback before performing the login :-)

Comment: which is the value of the sslPolicyErrors in ServerCertificateValidationCallback ?